# Add icon on bottom navigation bar in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So i have this issue that i can't add an icon in my bottom navigation bar,

here's the error i got:
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: number.

Check the render method of `Icon`.

I think my import for the icon image file is correct, and i have installed the library that i need for this

here's my code

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { HomeIcon, HomeIconActive, AbsensiIcon, AbsensiIconActive, KegiatanIcon, KegiatanIconActive, SettingIcon, SettingIconActive } from '../../assets'
import { warna_utama, warna_disable } from '../../assets'

const TabItem = ({ isFocused, onPress, onLongPress, label }) => {
    const Icon = () => {
        if (label === "Home") return isFocused ? <HomeIconActive /> : <HomeIcon />
        if (label === "Absensi") return isFocused ? <AbsensiIconActive /> : <AbsensiIcon />
        if (label === "Kegiatan") return isFocused ? <KegiatanIconActive /> : <KegiatanIcon />
        if (label === "Setting") return isFocused ? <SettingIconActive /> : <SettingIcon />
        return <HomeIcon />
    }
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={onPress}
            onLongPress={onLongPress}
            style={styles.container}
        >
            <Icon />
            <Text style={styles.text(isFocused)}>
                {label}
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}

export default TabItem

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    text: (isFocused) => ({
        fontSize: 13,
        color: isFocused ? warna_utama : warna_disable,
        marginTop: 5
    })
})
```

i want to add icon above the text

Comment: what is version of react native navigation you used ?

Comment: its' 0.72.4 i believe